# Is operating system Universal Turing Machine?

Tags: operating-systems, turing-completeness

The definition of UTM(Universal Turing Machine) is a Turing machine that can
simulate other Turing machines, so as far as I can guess operating system is a
UTM, since it can run multiple programs on a OS.

Comment: This question probably would be better on https://cs.stackexchange.com. I think you are mixing several concepts here. Turing Machines  are a mathematical abstraction, as they require infinite storage.You may be thinking of the concept of [Turing completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), which is a quality of a computer language or instruction set.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant I meant just the similarity between OS and UTM I was guessing like concept of operating system was influenced by UTM . . .

Comment: OSs have *the same computational power* as Turing machines: they can compute everything that is computable. However, they *are* something different. For instance, they usually have random-access mass storage, not sequential-access like Turing machines.

Comment: Please, provide a *precise* and *unambiguous* definition of what it means to "be" a Universal Turing Machine. Otherwise, it is impossible to tell whether or not an Operating System "is" a Universal Turing Machine if you don't tell us what *exactly* you mean by "is".

Comment: All computers are subsets of Turing machines.  No Turing machine can truly exist because it would require infinite memory, but in practical terms, computers are Turing machines and the software contained on them are like Turing machines within the Turing machine.  To call an operating system a universal turing machine is incredibly optimistic, even if we're assuming a computer is a Turing machine.  There are many many programs which cannot be run in an operating system, though they may be valid programs.

Comment: No, because an operating system is not a Turing machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An operating system is just a software framework.  You don't need an operating system to run multiple programs; software programs can run quite happily without it.  You need an operating system because of the services that it provides.

Change your question to ask about any other service-oriented framework, and it still makes sense (even though the answer is still no).

> The definition of UTM(Universal Turing Machine) is a Turing machine that can simulate other Turing machines, so as far as I can guess **Angular 2** is a UTM, since it can run multiple programs on **Angular 2**.

Where you're getting hung up here is on the word *simulation.*  An OS does not *simulate* a Turing machine in order to run your programs.  That is not its purpose.